# Setter for Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top readwrite in WPF but not in Silverlight 4, why?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, styles, setter

I have the following XAML, which works fine in WPF, but not in Silverlight 4

```
       <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ContentListBoxItemsPanelTemplate">
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentListBoxItemTemplate">
            <Border CornerRadius="15" Width="150" Margin="3" Height="300">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="OrangeRed" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Brown" Offset="0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
        </Style>
```

And then somewhere:

```
 <ListBox Name="ContentList" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContentListBoxItemTemplate}"
          ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ContentListBoxItemsPanelTemplate}" />
```

If I try the same thing in Silverlight I get an exception saying that the setter cannot set a read only property, but I still want to achieve the same thing in Silverlight without code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight does not support bindings in the value of the setter.  David Anson has a great workaround here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/05/07/one-more-platform-difference-more-or-less-tamed-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better.aspx

Comment: I like the link, but that gives me: Unable to access DependencyProperty "Canvas.Top" on type "ListBoxItem". thrown by the SetterValueBindingHelper class

Comment: Ah it seems I forgot the Type parameter. But still it does not work 100% only the last setter works... contacted the author, if he can fix this of course I'll mark your answer as the solution

Comment: There is an updated version here that solves it 
http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx